# wicket: set intercept page on authorization failure

Tags: java, authentication, wicket

I'm using wickets Role based authorization with annotations.
now I want to set an intercept page to go to on authorization or authentication failure. how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check wicket-examples' authentication examples.

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/authentication1/

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/authentication2/

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/authentication3/

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/authorization/

The sources can be found at https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples